# Calculated Member to aggregate measure over time in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, pyramid-analytics

I am looking to create a calculated member in SSAS 2012 that aggregates a "Confirmed" measure over a "Confirmed Month" hierarchy from the "Confirmed Date" dimension. I have attached a screenshot from a tool called "Pyramid Analytics" that shows what I have so far. I have also attached a screenshot of how the "Confirmed Date" dimension is laid out in BIDS. So, for each month in the future, the calculated member should aggregate the data to include the "confirmed" count for that month plus the "confirmed" count from all the previous months.

I am not very comfortable with writing MDX and I would be very grateful if someone could get me started. Thanks.

[image][image]

Comment: I know you would like us to get you started but have you tried anything yet? This forum works better if you make an attempt and then paste in your code.

Comment: this calculated member will be part of which existing dimension? The confirmed date dimension?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I looked up some MD examples online, but couldn't get the syntax to work. The calculated member will be part of the confirmed date dimension.

Comment: you could try it as a calculated member in Pyramid

Comment: please add the syntax that you've tried which doesn't work - this will help us